# subtract keys from dictionary if values match and return difference in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to subtract the keys of two dicts if their values match. One dict looks like this

```
dict_one
{(2, 2): 38,
 (2, 6): 51,
 (4, 9): 29,
 (5, 1): 53,
 (6, 6): 91,
 (6, 9): 105,
 (7, 6): 66,
 (8, 4): 74,
 (8, 8): 89,
 (9, 6): 115}
```

The other like this

```
dict_two
{(2, 1): 38,
 (2, 6): 51,
 (4, 9): 29,
 (5, 1): 53,
 (6, 6): 91,
 (6, 9): 105,
 (7, 6): 66,
 (8, 4): 74,
 (8, 8): 89,
 (9, 6): 115
```

In the example here the result should be

```
result
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Basically the value `38` in this example changed keys from `(2,2)` to `(2,1)`. so the difference between these pairs of values is `1`, whereas every other key stayed the same between the two dicts so the output values for the other keys are all `0`.

Comment: There is no ordering in dictionaries. What is the expected output order, sorted keys?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, so you probably have a way to generate the keys in an order that suits you. If so, the solution is obvious!

Comment: If you are matching by *value*, then it would appear you have your dictionary mapping the wrong way around. If the values are uique, then just invert the dictionaries, then simply subtract the second values in the tuples for each key.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for changed *keys*, then it appears you have your key-value mapping order the wrong way around. Invert one of the dictionaries, so you can easily look up the corresponding tuple for a given value.

Then loop over the *sorted* key-value pairs of the other:

```
inverted_dict_one = {v: k for k, v in dict_one.items()}
result = [abs(k[1] - inverted_dict_one[v][1] for k, v in sorted(dict_two.items())]
```

Demo:

```
>>> inverted_dict_one = {v: k for k, v in dict_one.items()}
>>> [abs(k[1] - inverted_dict_one[v][1]) for k, v in sorted(dict_two.items())]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```